# why doesn't my meta variables catch correctly?

Tags: python, metadata

I want to transfer my variables into the `parse_seleniums_method` method.  At the moment it doesn't work correctly. It saves one link and one address in 15-20 results.

How can I do it so that when I transfer them, each result from "url6" and from "address" corresponds correctly to the specific attribute.
What should I add and where?

My code is :

```py
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    json_info: dict = json.loads(response.body)
    for entity_info in json_info["details"]["list"]:
        entity_id = entity_info.get("id")
        entity_link = (
            "https://nemokumas.avnt.lt/action/public/case/"
            + entity_id
            + "?viewType=25087"
        )
        yield scrapy.Request(
            entity_link,
            callback=self.parse_entity,
            meta={"entity_id": entity_id},
        )

def parse_entity(self, response):
    entity_id = response.meta.get("entity_id")
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "xml")
    url6 = (
        "https://nemokumas.avnt.lt/public/case/edit/info?uuid=" + entity_id
    )
    all_address_codes = bs.find_all("address")
    if all_address_codes:
        address = all_address_codes[-1].text.strip()
    yield scrapy.Request(url="https://nemokumas.avnt.lt/public/case/list?filter=%7B%22category%22:%22LEGAL%22,%22page%22:1,%22pageSize%22:1802,%22date%22:%5B%5D,%22debtorBirthDate%22:%5B%5D,%22deregistrationDate%22:%5B%5D,%22terminationDate%22:%5B%5D,%22processTerminationDate%22:%5B%5D,%22endDate%22:%5B%5D,%22simplifiedCaseDate%22:%5B%5D,%22approvalDate%22:%5B%5D,%22liquidationDate%22:%5B%5D,%22endEnactmentDate%22:%5B%5D,%22completionDate%22:%5B%5D,%22viewType%22:%7B%22viewType%22:138,%22userType%22:%22UUID_FULLNAME_TYPE%22%7D,%22resourceStatusEnumList%22:%5B%22ACTIVE%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%22date%22,%22sortingOrder%22:%22desc%22,%22resourceStatusEnum%22:%22ACTIVE%22,%22nullFirst%22:false%7D", callback=self.parse_seleniums_method, dont_filter=True, meta={"url6": url6, "address": address})

def parse_seleniums_method(self, response):
    url6 = response.meta["url6"]
    address = response.meta["address"]
    self.driver.get(response.url)

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
        ec.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH,
             "//tbody[@ui-sortable='uiSortable']//tr")
        )
    )
    html_source = self.driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")
    response = Selector(text=html_source)
    rows = response.xpath("//tbody[@ui-sortable='uiSortable']//tr")
    for row in rows:

        name = row.xpath(
            "./td[@ng-if='!item.group'][2]//text()").get()
        pass
        item = DefaultRdcItem()
        item["url6"] = url6
        item["addr_rawFormat"] = address
```